# React FacebookAuth Error: FB.login() called before FB.init()

Tags: node.js, facebook, reactjs, environment-variables

I'm using the admin-on-rest npm package starter project and trying to plug in a simple SSO Facebook login button using the FacebookAuth npm package.  Every time I try to click the "Login" button, I get the following error:

> FB.login() called before FB.init()

I'm using an .env file with the following variable: REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_APP_ID and setting it to the right value.  I even did console.log() within my app and can see it output.

I checked and I'm only loading the FB SDK once, not multiple times (this was a common issue reported on other threads).

Answer (score 7):

Ok, it turned out to be something pretty dumb, but something to point out nonetheless!

In my .env file, I had accidentally placed a semicolon (;) at the end of the declaration, like this:

```
REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_APP_ID = XXXXXXXXXXXX;
```

Apparently .env files do NOT like semi-colons.  This was just very difficult to figure out from the error above.

So if any of you want to pull your hair out because of this issue, and you're using similar tech, check to make sure you're syntactically kosher EVERYWHERE variables are being declared.

Answer (score 0):

the funny thing was i forgot to replace your-app-id with my app id:

```
<script>
    FB.init({
      appId: 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents: true,
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v8.0'
    });
  </script>
```